# maya component id data

Tags: python, maya

Does anyone know how to obtain the data in maya called the component ID of the vertices.

I know how to get the vert number but the component ID on the vert is something that changes as the model has been changed.

It seems that there is data in the vertex but just can't find any command to extract it. Any help would be helpful.

I even tried using the maya api but this also just seem to give me the vertices index number and not the actual ID (which is not a sequence as the vertices indexes)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try that,

```
import maya.OpenMaya as om
sel = om.MSelectionList()
om.MGlobal.getActiveSelectionList(sel)
dag = om.MDagPath()
comp = om.MObject()
sel.getDagPath(0, dag, comp)
itr = om.MItMeshFaceVertex(dag, comp)
print '| %-15s| %-15s| %-15s' % ('Face ID', 'Object VertID', 'Face-relative VertId')
while not itr.isDone():
    print '| %-15s| %-15s| %-15s' % (itr.faceId(), itr.vertId(), itr.faceVertId())
    itr.next()
```

there are many solutions, i find this one.... src: [Link](http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?3649-OpenMaya-getting-the-current-componet-selection)

Comment: `vertID` is going to be the same as the vertex index; `faceVertID` is the position of the vert in the face-vertex array.   It sounds like OP is asking for some kind of 'absolute vertex id', which Maya does not provide.

Comment: Thanks Ali Gold but theodox is correct by saying the above solution will not give the true component ID.  At first the vert  ID and component ID are the same until you start editing the model it changes a lot.  It is strange that there is a function in maya to display the component ID but not access it within a script?

Answer (score 0):

Maya components do not have persistent identities; the 'vertex id' is just the index of one entry in the vertex table (or the tables for faces, normals, etc).  That's why its so easy to mess up a model with construction history if you go 'upstream' and change things that affect the model's component count or topology.

You can attach persistent data to a vertex using the [PolyBlindData](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/index.html?url=files/Blind_data_What_is_blind_data_.htm,topicNumber=d30e168928) system, which attaches arbitrary info to faces, vertices or edges. You could attach data to a particular vertex and the data would *probably* survive, though the same considerations which can mess up things like vert colors or UVs when construction history changes upstream will also mess with blind data.

Comment: The weird part is that component I'd is something you can view and its alwayse there.  Just have to switch it on. Surely there must be a way to access it through a script?